# If $h$ is element of a subgroup $H$ of the group $G$, all elements in the conjugacy class of $h$ in $G$ necessarily are members of that subgroup, too.

Tags: group-theory

I started studying group theory a little while ago and now came across this statement that I am not sure why it is true?

Can someone provide me with a proof. I am sure it is not difficult, but I just do not see it.

Comment: Normal subgroup?

Comment: Do you mean the conjugacy class of $h$ in $H$? Or the conjugacy class of $h$ in $G$?

Comment: Let $G=S_3$ be the group of permutations of $\{1,2,3\}$, let $H=\{\operatorname{id},(1\,2)\}$. Note that $(1\,2\,3)^{-1}(1\,2)(1\,2\,3)=(1\,3)$

Comment: Right, the example shows that it cant be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true in general.

For example, take $G = S_n$ to be the symmetric group on $n\ge 3$ letters, and set $H=\langle(1~2)\rangle$. The conjugates of $(1~2)$ are all the transpositions $(i~j)$, but $H = \{e, (1~2)\}$ does **not** contain all of these conjugates.

However, this is true for **normal** subgroups. If $H\le G$ is normal, then $gHg^{-1}\subseteq H$ for all $g\in G$. Given any $h\in H$, this means that $ghg^{-1}\in H$, so all conjugates of $h$ are in $H$.

Comment: No wonder, I could not prove it, then. Thank you for clarifying. What is meant by H $\leq$ G though?

Comment: @Marsl For a group $G$, the notation $H\le G$ means that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @Marsl where did you "come across this statement"?